# Android Development - using WebView to pull in an iframe with a google maps reference is not showing custom markers

Tags: android, google-maps, android-webview

I am building a realty app that relies on pulling in some HTML that was generated from the trulia.com tools page from [this location](http://www.trulia.com/tools/map-search/).

The problem I'm encountering is that when I use WebView to pull in this html it will not show the markers on the iframe that point to the property locations on the map and show the price of the home located there.  I have javascript enabled on the WebView and the map shows up just fine, just not the markers.

Does anyone have any experience getting these markers to work with WebView.  And please don't tell me to just use Google Maps API.  This is supposed to be a simple solution.  Thanks ahead of time.

UPDATE:

Here is the html I am pulling in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://css.trulia-cdn.com/css/G26_32/css/pg_truliatool-generate.css"><div class="trulia_tool container300x250 map-search green" style="width: 296px; height: 250px;"><div class="trulia_tool_header"><h6>Map Search</h6></div><iframe height="400px" src="http://synd.trulia.com/tools/map-search/embedded?params%5Blocation%5D=Idaho+Falls%2C+ID&params%5BlocationId%5D=19191&params%5Bagent_id%5D=&params%5Bproperty_status%5D=for+sale&params%5Btitle%5D=Map+Search&params%5Bcolor%5D=green&params%5Bemail%5D=&params%5Buser_url%5D=&params%5Bwidth%5D=300&params%5Bheight%5D=250&params%5Bguid%5D=53ced10419feb" style="height: 185px; overflow: hidden;"><p>Your browser does not support iframes</p></iframe><div class="trulia_tool_footer"><div class="footer-link typeTruncate"><a href="http://www.trulia.com/for_sale/Idaho_Falls,ID/" title="See homes in Idaho Falls, ID" target="_blank">See homes in</a><br /><span>Idaho Falls, ID</span></div><a class="trulia-logo" href="http://www.trulia.com/" title="Trulia" target="_blank"></a></div>
```

UPDATE:

Here are the logcat messages:

07-24 02:59:30.444    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
07-24 02:59:30.456    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/BrowserProcessMain﹕ Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
07-24 02:59:30.528    2239-2264/com.example.FranciscoBarreto W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
07-24 02:59:30.652    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 290K, 3% free 14391K/14788K, paused 13ms, total 14ms
07-24 02:59:30.760    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 16.572MB for 2536932-byte allocation
07-24 02:59:30.808    2239-2248/com.example.FranciscoBarreto D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 16867K/17268K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
07-24 02:59:30.972    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 02:59:31.140    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-24 02:59:31.164    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-24 02:59:32.464    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-24 02:59:32.884    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-24 02:59:32.968    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-24 02:59:33.232    2239-2278/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/chromium﹕ [INFO:simple_index_file.cc(397)] Simple Cache Index is being restored from disk.
07-24 02:59:33.416    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
07-24 02:59:33.936    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
07-24 02:59:34.548    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
07-24 02:59:34.560    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 02:59:36.072    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
07-24 02:59:38.448    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
07-24 02:59:38.460    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 108 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 02:59:39.108    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
07-24 02:59:39.116    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto D/MyApplication﹕ Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined -- From line 1 of
07-24 02:59:39.116    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", source:  (1)
07-24 02:59:39.116    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto D/MyApplication﹕ Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined -- From line 1 of
07-24 02:59:39.116    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", source:  (1)
07-24 02:59:40.512    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto D/MyApplication﹕ XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://m.trulia.com/_ajax/Location/LocalComps/get_comps/?b=43.547073,-111.937025,43.555782,-111.911619&v=city&c=Idaho%20Falls&s=ID&z=&n=&t=for%20sale. Origin http://synd.trulia.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. -- From line 0 of http://synd.trulia.com/tools/map-search/embedded?params%5Blocation%5D=Idaho+Falls%2C+ID&params%5BlocationId%5D=19191&params%5Bagent_id%5D=&params%5Bproperty_status%5D=for+sale&params%5Btitle%5D=Map+Search&params%5Bcolor%5D=green&params%5Bemail%5D=&params%5Buser_url%5D=&params%5Bwidth%5D=300&params%5Bheight%5D=250&params%5Bguid%5D=53cc7419073a5
07-24 02:59:40.512    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://m.trulia.com/_ajax/Location/LocalComps/get_comps/?b=43.547073,-111.937025,43.555782,-111.911619&v=city&c=Idaho%20Falls&s=ID&z=&n=&t=for%20sale. Origin http://synd.trulia.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.", source: http://synd.trulia.com/tools/map-search/embedded?params%5Blocation%5D=Idaho+Falls%2C+ID&params%5BlocationId%5D=19191&params%5Bagent_id%5D=&params%5Bproperty_status%5D=for+sale&params%5Btitle%5D=Map+Search&params%5Bcolor%5D=green&params%5Bemail%5D=&params%5Buser_url%5D=&params%5Bwidth%5D=300&params%5Bheight%5D=250&params%5Bguid%5D=53cc7419073a5 (0)
07-24 02:59:42.460    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
07-24 02:59:42.472    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 92 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 02:59:42.476    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto D/MyApplication﹕ XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://m.trulia.com/_ajax/Location/LocalComps/get_comps/?b=43.487292,-112.046667,43.49601,-112.021262&v=city&c=Idaho%20Falls&s=ID&z=&n=&t=for%20sale. Origin http://synd.trulia.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. -- From line 0 of http://synd.trulia.com/tools/map-search/embedded?params%5Blocation%5D=Idaho+Falls%2C+ID&params%5BlocationId%5D=19191&params%5Bagent_id%5D=&params%5Bproperty_status%5D=for+sale&params%5Btitle%5D=Map+Search&params%5Bcolor%5D=green&params%5Bemail%5D=&params%5Buser_url%5D=&params%5Bwidth%5D=300&params%5Bheight%5D=250&params%5Bguid%5D=53cc7419073a5
07-24 02:59:42.476    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://m.trulia.com/_ajax/Location/LocalComps/get_comps/?b=43.487292,-112.046667,43.49601,-112.021262&v=city&c=Idaho%20Falls&s=ID&z=&n=&t=for%20sale. Origin http://synd.trulia.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.", source: http://synd.trulia.com/tools/map-search/embedded?params%5Blocation%5D=Idaho+Falls%2C+ID&params%5BlocationId%5D=19191&params%5Bagent_id%5D=&params%5Bproperty_status%5D=for+sale&params%5Btitle%5D=Map+Search&params%5Bcolor%5D=green&params%5Bemail%5D=&params%5Buser_url%5D=&params%5Bwidth%5D=300&params%5Bheight%5D=250&params%5Bguid%5D=53cc7419073a5 (0)
07-24 02:59:42.768    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
07-24 02:59:44.008    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
07-24 02:59:44.020    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 02:59:44.484    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
07-24 02:59:44.984    2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)

Comment: This is hard to say without knowing anything about the html/javascript coming from Trulia. You should try to log console messages from the WebView as documented [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html#WebView). It sounds like there is some javascript error that is occurring when the iframe is displayed in an Android WebView. See if you can debug it from there.

Comment: Thank you.  I have done a little digging with firebug but I suspect your suggestion will be much more helpful.  Just for reference, I'll update the question to contain the html/javascript I'm using in the WebView.

Comment: Looks good, I think you might see something important in the console logs from the Javascript execution within the iframe. If you can post some output from that, we might be able to debug it.

Comment: Also, you should look in Logcat to see if WebView or WebKit are logging any warnings or errors that might be relevant. Post any output for your process that might be related.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the ajax requests from Trulia are not going through. I've added an answer below. I haven't tested my solution, but let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the WebView content using a file containing the html you posted, or you are passing a String containing that html, you may need to use `setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs` to allow the WebView to make requests to other resources from scripts running on the page.

In your log post, it seems pretty apparent that this is the problem:

```
02:59:42.476 2239-2239/com.example.FranciscoBarreto D/MyApplication﹕ XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://m.trulia.com/_ajax/Location/LocalComps/get_comps/?b=43.487292,-112.046667,43.49601,-112.021262&v=city&c=Idaho%20Falls&s=ID&z=&n=&t=for%20sale. Origin http://synd.trulia.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. -- From line 0 of http://synd.trulia.com/tools/map-search/embedded?params%5Blocation%5D=Idaho+Falls%2C+ID&params%5BlocationId%5D=19191&params%5Bagent_id%5D=&params%5Bproperty_status%5D=for+sale&params%5Btitle%5D=Map+Search&params%5Bcolor%5D=green&params%5Bemail%5D=&params%5Buser_url%5D=&params%5Bwidth%5D=300&params%5Bheight%5D=250&params%5Bguid%5D=53cc7419073a5
```

The javascript running on the page, which Trulia fetches, is trying to retrieve the locations to display using an Ajax call, given the coordinates for your area. This is failing because the browser isn't allowing any network calls to a new "Origin" address, which will be any address if you are not loading a remote page in the WebView.

Try using this call on the webView to allow these requests to go through:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  So I've been trying that but it keeps telling me that the method setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs could not be found.  I've been looking everywhere for an answer as to why.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check your target API level for the project in AndroidManifest.xml. It must greater than or equal to jelly bean (API level 16).